# Can't change body height reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm discovering ReactJS, trying some stuff but i face a problem: my body height is fixed to 76px and i can't do anything to that, i tried a lot a stuff, nothing worked.
Here's the code i'm using

```
import * as React from 'react';

// This fonction make the color change on the button on the first click
function ChangeStyle() {
       var elem = document.getElementById('Button1');
       if (elem == null) {
         return;
       }
       elem.style.background = '#ff4848';

}

// Main Class
export class Button extends React.Component {
    render() {

        // Style sheet of the Button
        var buttonStyle = {
            fontSize: 50,
            background: '#ffb516',
            color : '#FFFFFF',
            width: 500,
            border: 'none',
            textAlign: 'center',
            display: 'block',
            margin: 'auto'  
        };

        // Set the Background color
        document.body.style.backgroundColor =  '#25353f';
        document.body.style.position = 'relative';
        document.body.style.height = '100%';

        // Try to make the button in center
        /*
            var centerDiv = {
                position: 'absolute' as 'absolute',
                top: '50%',
                left: '30%',  
                margin: 'auto'      
            }
        */

        // Test on linearGradient
        /*
            function degraded() {
                <svg width='15' height='71' fill='url(#Gradient-1)'>
                    <defs>
                        <linearGradient id='Gradient-1' x2='0%' y2='100%'>
                        <stop offset='0%' stop-color='#25353f'/> 
                        <stop offset='100%' stop-color='#5b6c72'/>    
                        </linearGradient>
                    </defs>
                </svg>
            }
        */

        // Create the button
        return (   
            <div id="fullHeight" style={{height: '100%'}}>
                <div /*style={centerDiv}*/>           
                        <button 
                            id="Button1" 
                            style={buttonStyle}
                            onClick={() => ChangeStyle()}
                        >
                            Pushtalents
                        </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );

    }
}

export default Button;
```

Any idea why? And how to fix this problem?

Comment: Do not mind the comment, forgot to delete my try for a gradient background...

Comment: you might need to set `html {height:100%}`

Comment: I already tried, doesn't work ;(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps if you remove `position: relative;` from body. It doesn't do anything anyways. Other than that you can try to set the body height to `100vh`.